# Creating cruds and authentication for users in my node.js(specifically Nest.js) application using Azure Ad?

Tags: node.js, database, azure, server, azure-active-directory

I am building a Web/Mobile application and i want to store my users in a Azure server and manage authentication and cruds. 
My question is, can i create CRUD's and authentication for managing users in Azure Ad. 
I want to do this using code in node.js (specifically Nest.js). 
For example: When a user registers in my app it sends a request to Azure server to create the user, or for example an admin wants to create/update/delete a user from my app to Azure Ad? 
Is this possible, if yes can someone send me a documentation for implementing it in node.js? 
What i found is : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0 
And managining users: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Not an answer as such, but sounds you may have more of a use case for Azure AD B2C which has user sign-up flows built in. [Azure AD B2C docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview)

Comment: So this is not possible to do using Azure, i know this can be done using Firebase, but what about AWS, i head about AWS IAM

Comment: Have you tried MS Graph API/Az AD Graph API for CRUD workflow? You might want to refer to the official MSAL documentation for insights